# Easy-to-use bandwidth throttler for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bandwidth, bandwidth-control, file-server

I have a Minecraft server and a file server that I host on the same box.  I want to set it up so that if someone is playing Minecraft and I'm pushing or pulling files, that neither application hogs all the bandwidth.

Some additional notes:

- I'm using Ubuntu.
- Simple is better than complex, even if it means slightly less than perfect performance
- Easy is better than hard, but hard is better than nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick search gave me [MasterShaper](http://www.mastershaper.org/index.php/MasterShaper), but when I worked at a wireless ISP I used [htb.init](http://sourceforge.net/projects/htbinit/) to shape my traffic. I know that DD-WRT (custom firmware for broadcom wireless routers) has a very good QOS interface (I use it to keep the torrents from slowing everything else).

Take a look at both projects, I know that htb.init config is made via text files and not that complex, but MasterShaper is a newer project and may be even easier with web interface, graphs and an option to use [Layer 7](http://l7-filter.sourceforge.net/) classifiers.